# if else in list comprehension with for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I've written my own simple solution for flatten list:

```
lists = [0, 10, [20, 30], 40, 50, [60, 70, 80], [90, 100, 110, 120]]
new = []
for item in lists:
    if str(item).isdigit() != True:
        for v in item:
            new.append(v)
    else:
        new.append(item)
print(new)
```

But I want to add an `else`/`elif` to the following code to make code shorter:

```
new = [v for item in lists if str(item).isdigit() != True for v in item]
```

I don't know how to rather getting syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some notes for your original code:

1. Instead of

   ```
   if str(item).isdigit() != True:
   ```

   use more Pythonic

   ```
   if not str(item).isdigit():
   ```
2. Instead of the same, speculative way to reach your goal, use more clear

   ```
   if type(item) is not list:
   ```

Now, about `else` in list comprehension. It may be only in the first part of it, syntax of list comprehension don't allow it after the `for` clause (in `if` filtering expressions).

So you need to change the iterable in the second `for` of your list comprehension to always be an iterable, i.e. for example for `item`

- `[20, 30]` it is OK (because it *is* an iterable)
- `10` it is *not* OK (because it is *not* an iterable) - so let's put bracket around it - `[10]`

So we will switch between `item` and `[item]` depending of `type(item)`:

```
 item     if type(item) is list     else     [item]
```

(It is a *conditional expression*, not a list comprehension, so `else` is OK here.)

So the full solution may be

```
new = [v for item in lists 
         for v in (item if type(item) is list else [item])]
```

Comment: Your preciseness of describing clarifications in this fact was incredible. Thanks for the help buddy!

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
>>> [v for item in lists for v in (item if isinstance(item, list) else [item])]
[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]
```

This is slightly inefficient as it wraps an integer into a list, then iterates it, but it shouldn't matter for most purposes. Try not to use string representations for checking data types as you may end up with unexpected results (try running your original code with a float instead of an integer in the list for example).

Comment: for the sake of completeness, I would mention: `collections.abc.Iterable`

Comment: @Aaron Honestly that felt like too much work as it is not reliable either. Calling `iter` and catching exceptions is the way to go, but that would complicate this example and miss the point.

Comment: According to your solution I figured out my new one haha.. thanks buddy :) `new = [v for item in lists for v in (item if str(item).isdigit() != True else [item])]`